# Display wordpress sub-category posts on sub-category page

Tags: php, categories, wordpress

I'm trying to get a WP function to work properly.

I want it to display the posts from the selected sub-category page, for example, when navigating to: [www.example.com/category/fruits/apples/](http://www.example.com/category/fruits/apples/), display all custom posts under "apples" category. I want to do this dynamically, so that no matter the number of sub-categories (apples, oranges, pears etc) this works every time the sub-category page is visited.

The following is my current function, but I don't know if the `get_query_var('cat')` is implemented properly. Currently, when I visit the sub-category page, it displays ALL posts with the parent category "fruits", but I want it to display just the "apples" posts.

```
<?php

$cat = get_query_var('cat'); // get current category
$yourcat = get_category($cat);

// only display product CPT posts 
query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'products' ) ); 

if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="more"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><span class="fa fa-location-arrow"></span></a></div>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <div class="caption">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-default" role="button"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: I think I've managed to solve this! I wasn't familiar with the query posts, but after looking at the codex, found what I was looking for. Here's the updated bit of code:

`$category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
$cat = $category->cat_name;

// only display product CPT posts
query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'products', 'category_name' => $cat ) );`

Comment: Well done. Put the adjusted code in an answer and mark it solved. This will make it easier for people to identify unsolved issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added $cat variable to query_posts array to get the current selected category posts.

```
$category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
$cat = $category->cat_name;

// only display product CPT
posts query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'products', 'category_name' => $cat ) );
```